# How to handle multiple onPress in react native

Tags: react-native, react-props

I have a modal component their I have two buttons and one imageView.

```js
const ImageModal = ({ modalOpen, onClose, returnButton, customerImage, nextPage, nextPageText }) => {
  const { container, modalToggle, modalClose, imageStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType='slide'>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.ButtonsContainer}>
          
           {/* Button number 1*/}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClose}>
            <View style={styles.buttonView}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>{returnButton}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          {/* Button number 2*/}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={nextPage}>
            <View style={styles.buttonView}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>{nextPageText}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
        <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={customerImage} />
      </View>
    </Modal>
```

and i have import this component to my screen component.

```js
<Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType='slide'>
   <ImageModal 
       returnButton="Ta om" 
       onClose={()=> setModalOpen(false)} 
       customerImage={{uri: image}}
       nextPage={() => navigation.navigate('SaveCase', { image })}
       nextPageText="Välj"
   />
</Modal>
```

But when run the App I can only press one button(onClose). But sometimes that button works on both "onClose" and "nextPage" props.

Answer (score 0):

From your code is hard to say with certainty where the issue lies.

Possible reasons could be:

- your buttons are overlapping (most common),
- you are using props incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea how to solve this? I found out if I press "onClose" first it closes my modal as it should. But if I press "nextPage" and then "onClose", it navigate to my page "SaveCase". It's like my "next page" button works like a checkbox.